# reactVR model texture how to load local resource?

Tags: textures, react-360

I am new to reactVR, and I want to load local resource on my Model texture, here is the code:

```
<Model
  source={{obj: asset('Tree.obj')}}
  style={{transform: [{translate: [0, -1, -3]}]}}
  texture={asset('14HMTcQb.jpg')}
/>
```

and I get a empty screen. So how to load my local resource on texture via ReactVR?

Comment: Did your `obj` come with a companion `mtl` file? Could you upload them to a github gist?

Comment: @Valentin Okay, I will upload it to the github.

Comment: @Valentin Today, I test it, it works. Besides, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem, good luck on your VR journey!

Answer (score 0):

Code looks great, do you have any js errors or network errors loading the resources?

Also make sure you

import {
    Model,
    asset
} from 'react-vr';

and also you place your 'Tree.obj' and '14HMTcQb.jpg' files under your static_assets directory on the project root.